# using System.data.Sqlite with different platforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am working on a C# .Net Windows app. I am using `system.data.sqlite`. It's working when I change the **platform target** to **x86**. It means it will work at the 32 bit system.

My question is what if I need to install the app on a 64 bit machine in future? I want it to work with both platforms, 32 bit and 64 bit.

Is there any way to make it work for both processor architectures in one go?

Answer (score 0):

according to nuget package info you are getting 32/64 versions in one go.
Just switch version of your app and test it - this will give you confidence in this topic.

[Nuget Info](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)